# 'href' Not Showing Output on Click

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to have a href link expand/display extra text when clicked however when I click it nothing happens.

When I run the html code I can click on the link but it does not show the text for some reason.
Any idea why?

Heres the code:

```
<html>
<a href="#1" onclick="$('divID').toggle();">click to expand</a>
<div id="divID" style="display: none;">this is expanded</div>
</html>
```

I'm trying to keep the code as short as possible as the above code will have to be repeated hundreds of times for each link.

Comment: check the browser console and look for any javascript error.

Comment: show your javascript code

Comment: also, ou might use the # when selecting a element by ID $('#divID')

Comment: Both your syntax and the method you're calling are jQuery, which is a JavaScript library. Be sure you understand the distinction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using jQuery, you are using the CSS selector incorrectly. Your line should be this:

```
<a href="#1" onclick="$('#divID').toggle();">click to expand</a>
```

The `#` in `#divID` represents any element with an `id` of `divID`, whereas just using `divID` will search for `divID` tags (something like `<divID></divID>`)

[See here for more documentation on the ID Selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and [here's a list of all the CSS selectors you can use](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), including [the Element Selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) for you to understand why your previous code didn't work.

You can also combine CSS selectors to narrow your selection in the future, although it's not much necessary with an ID selector:

```
<a href="#1" onclick="$('div#divID').toggle();">click to expand</a>
```

And if you absolutely insist on **not** using jQuery:

```
<a href="#1" onclick="if (document.getElementById('divId').style.display == 'none') document.getElementById('divId').style.display = 'block'; else document.getElementById('divId').style.display = 'none';">click to expand</a>
```

or breaking it out into its own function:

```
<script>
    function toggleElementById(id) {
        if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'none') {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>
<a href="#1" onclick="toggleElementById('divId');">click to expand</a>
```

Comment: Hi, Im not using jquery
Ive changed the code but it is just doing the same thing
In the CSS file the ID is #link

Comment: @snipe [Then get it.](http://jquery.com/download/) [`.toggle()` is an API function that is exclusive to jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), as well as the CSS selector. Without jQuery you will have to use [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) and write your own custom script that changes the `display: none;` property of your `div` element, which is a much bigger hassle than just including jQuery in your HTML.

Comment: @snipe Either way, I've added one more edit for a non-jQuery answer.

Comment: I'd recommend turning the non-jQuery way into a function since OP wants to use it multiple times. Showing how it may look would be helpful probably

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then:

```
$('#divID').toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using jQuery, right? So I wrote your answer in jQuery..

```
$('.toggle').click(function () {
    var selected = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.expandable'+selected).toggle();
});
```

[Check out the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fleuv/d9sm1tc7/)

If you're not using jQuery than here is the javascript version (html changed).

```
var expandable = document.getElementsByClassName("expandable");
for (i = 0; i < expandable.length; ++i) {
    expandable[i].setAttribute('style','display: none;');
}
var toggle = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle");
for (i = 0; i < toggle.length; ++i) {
    toggle[i].setAttribute('onclick','toggler(this)');
}
function toggler(obj) {
    var id = obj.dataset.toggle,
        el = document.getElementById(id);
    el.style.display = (el.style.display != 'none' ? 'none' : '');
}
```

[Check out the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fleuv/vft6jvmk/)

Comment: OP [is not using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741988/href-not-showing-output-on-click#comment42069960_26742029)